# ffmpeg EOF error when converting stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to capture a single frame and save as a image file using ffmpeg from the command line in linux.
I am using the command below with other streams without any issues. With one stream I am getting an error that looks like "http://ip: End of file"

ffmpeg -i http://ip -r 1 -qscale 1 -vframes 1  -y -f image2 t.jpg

I am not sure what is different between these stream except maybe a different resolution.
I was wondering if anything can be changed or added to the command to possibly get this stream to work?

thanks

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: thank you. are you referring to the information in the terminal window or a different log?

Comment: The terminal window. Add `2> log.txt` to capture it to a file.